# lxml installed but not found in python 3.4 on virtualenv on a AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualenv, lxml, python-3.4

I have installed lxml on my AWS EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI), inside my virtualenv:

```
pip3 install lxml
```

and I got the following result:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... done
Successfully installed lxml
```

However, lxml appears not to be installed. When I import it in a python 3.4 script:

```
from lxml import html
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
```

Furthermore, if I run:

```
pip3 uninstall lxml
```

I get

```
Cannot uninstall requirement lxml, not installed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install for python2 or 3?

Comment: I guess that for python 3 since I used pip3 (as I added in the question). Can I check it in any way?

Comment: What does `which -a python3` output?

Comment: `~/virtualenvs/pablo/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Ok, are you using the virtualenv?

Comment: yes. I should have told that too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112709/discussion-between-pablo-guerrero-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using easy_install instead of pip:

```
easy_install lxml
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I had installed `python-devel` but that was just for Python 2.  So for Python 3, do:

`sudo yum install python34-devel`

Or if you're on Debian:

`sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev`